# Wirelessly transmit sensors status

Tags: sensor, home-automation

I am currently working on a home automation system and one of the challenges is big distances between my sensors and the the Raspberry Pi.

For instance, I would like to monitor two rooms with PIR sensors. Connecting via cable wouldn't be an option since we are talking about over 7 meters.

[image: PIR SENSOR]

How can I wirelessly transmit sensor status (e.g.: PIR which is a simple high/low) to my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I suggest you look at Arduino and wireless because if you can't use wire you'll need a remote processor and a remote wireless unit.

Comment: The same way everyone else does it -- sorcery!   This seems a bit like "How do I ride a horse?" in that the answer is in the question, *you wirelessly transmit it*.   No matter how you slice it, as joan points out additional equipment and/or very fast, tireless, probably tiny and winged porters are required.   Note that wireless transmission requires *power* which is why it is often best done via a dedicated router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you might do this. First of all, the simplest: Use two Raspberry Pis and connect them to a wireless network. Secondly, you could use Arduinos with RF wireless transmitters and a receiver on the Raspberry Pi. Take a look at the RasWIK (Wireless Inventors Kit - http://shop.ciseco.co.uk/raswik/) from Ciseco. It gives you an Arduino with built-in wireless capability and a GPIO plug-in board for the Pi allowing wireless communication between the two of them. Not sure how you'd do it for multiple sensors, but that's part of the fun.